# Regex to mask characters except first two digits in Java

Tags: java, regex, salesforce, apex

In Apex, I want to write a regular expression to do the following:

```
source string: abcdefg
output string: ab*****

source string: 123456789
output string: 12*******

source string: a123d
output string: a1***
```

What I have tried so far:

```
String t= "salesforce"; 
String r = t.replaceAll("\\w(?=\\w{2})", "*"); 
system.debug("==r=="+r);
```

**output :**

```
********ce
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: And why a regex?

Comment: string t= 'salesforce';
String r = t.replaceAll('\\w(?=\\w{2})', '*');
system.debug('==r=='+r);

output : ********ce

Comment: @RaJu put it in the question, please.

Comment: Please give an expression to get the desired output

Comment: Apex is not Java.

Comment: Is the question Apex related or Java related? Anyway try my answer hereunder and let me know if it works for you

Comment: It's Working, Thanks.. @Allan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to make the trick:

```
String t= "salesforce"; 
String r = t.replaceAll("(?<=..).", "*"); 
System.out.println("output: "+r);
```

**output:**

```
output: sa********
```

**Explanations:**

`(?<=..).` the regex will identify every character from the string respecting the constraint that there exist 2 character before it, this will work from the 3rd character until the end of the string as shown hereunder, then you just replace those characters by a `*`

**DEMO**: https://regex101.com/r/gvMoDi/1/